# VBA Excel : Automatically change the file path

Tags: excel, vba

My file has been saved at a particular path with a name `Ankit1.xls`. It has macro coding and is working fine. But my question is that whenever I change the file name the macro doesn't work. I need to change the path in coding wherever needed. Please can someone help me in coding in such a way that whenever I change the file name the macro will automatically change the path and does not give me the error.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't show the code and at least ask a specific question. Also include in your question where your code fails, what you expect as result and what the actual result is.

Comment: *the macro doesn't work* is an absolutely meaningless problem description. In what way **specifically** does it **not work**? Do you get an error message? If  so, what is the **exact** error message you see? Does it produce the wrong results? If so,what result does it produce and what do you get instead? We can't see your screen or read your mind, so you need to give us the specifics in your question. You're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem**; you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so by giving us the details you have.

Comment: Everytime i rename my file name i need to change the coding. Is there any way where if rename my file also. I don't need to change the coding.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you need to change. We can't do anything without seeing your code!

Comment: Your question is one vote away from being closed. You need to to change parts of your code so that it's more dynamic and can pull the filename and path of the workbook in which it currently resides. We can't help you though since you haven't provided any code. If you wish the question to stay open and have someone help you, please supply the part of the code that is failing so that we can help you rewrite it. It's the only solution to your problem.

Comment: Sub Weekly()
'
' Weekly Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
    Sheets("Productvity1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").ClearTable
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Ankit\Automation\Ankit\[Visa SLO Dashboard V3.xls]Dump!R1C1:R65536C56" _
        , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)
Every time I rename the file. I need to change the code. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use `Thisworkbook` object in order to access data from `Ankit1.xls` file without changing the hardcoded constant that represents the workbook name.

Additionally you can code prior to this to check that the correct workbook has been opened.

Comment: This is a comment asking for clarification, not an answer. If you had comment privileges, you could post this to the original question properly. You do not have that privilege yet, however, but cannot use this space to circumvent that issue. This space is reserved for one (and only one) purpose, which is clearly stated by the heading above it; that purpose is to post **Your Answer**.

Comment: Everytime i rename my file name i need to change the coding. Is there any way where if rename my file also. I don't need to change the coding

Comment: Give us the part of the coding you need to change

Comment: Sub Weekly()
'
' Weekly Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
    Sheets("Productvity1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").ClearTable
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Ankit\Automation\Ankit\[Visa SLO Dashboard V3.xls]Dump!R1C1:R65536C56" _
        , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)
Every time I rename the file. I need to change the code. Please help

Comment: seems you need to replace the path in SourceData with `Thisworkbook.path & "\" & Thisworkbook.name`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for

```
ThisWorkbook.Name
```

or

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```